# Magento error after moving site to another hosting

Tags: mysql, magento, transfer

I have transfered my site(CMS Magento) on another hosting, but I have the  newest version on this  (Apache version  2.2.29 | PHP version    5.5.16 | MySQL version  5.6.16-cll-lve) not  like old host(about v5.1).
I get this error in frontend  "Fatal error: Call to a member function useLoadDataFields() on a non-object in /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Config.php on line 610" but the header is still working. I have opened the log and shows this error "a:5:{i:0;s:63:"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away";i:1;s:1580:"#0 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array).... ".
In admin when I log in I get this error "Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract' not found in /home/sexup/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Renderer/Text.php on line 37"

Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

> "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away"

did you set up the database connection in app/etc/config ?

if answer is yes, maybe problems are with your new host resources (some shared hostings are not appropriate for magento )?

under this link is explanation of db error http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html